# How do I "import" an AMD "defined" module from an import in a ".jsx" file in a REACT project?

Tags: reactjs, import, amd, jsx

I'm new to REACT. How do I "import" an AMD/requirejs "define" module from an import in a ".jsx" file in a REACT project?

Say you have...

```
define('project/module',[
    './Viewport'
]
```

In a JSX file, how can you import this ...

```
import "project/module"
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import existing AMD module into ES6 module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805234/import-existing-amd-module-into-es6-module)

Comment: import "project/module" -- webpack seems to be looking for "project/module.js"... In the example above "project/module" is in "project.js"... In another way to ask... How can I tell webpack to look for "project/module" in project.js (that has the "define") instead of looking for "project/module.js".