# how to import dojo modules in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dojo, amd

I'm developing a library that uses ArcGIS which based on `dojo` framework.

ArcGIS has main file that we include in the `<script>` Tag. And then we simple require their modules using `require('esri/map'...`.

My es6 library has allot of modules and part of them need to use ArcGIS modules.

I'm using webpack and babel to bundle and transform the code. I'm not bundling ArcGIS in my library single file. I'm expecting my clients to include esri adding `<script>` and then include my bundle using `<script>`.
There I've already met an obstacle - `dojo multiple define`... So I've made another `js` excluded from the bundle that loads my bundle file using dojo `require` that already exist (Cause arcgis is up already and loaded dojo).

Now, the second problem I don't manage to solve is to load other ArcGIS AMD modules..

I have my class `MyMap.js`

```
export default MyMap {
   constructor() {
      // Adding here code to create ArcGIS Map
      // this.map = new esriMap....
   }
}
```

`esriMap` does not exist and must be loaded. In a simple application we would do this to make it happen

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView"
], function(Map, MapView) {

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    zoom: 4,
    center: [15, 65]
  });

});
```

but this does not work.

someone ?

Comment: Have you seen this [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/180988)?

Comment: I've seen this before but I saw that it is typescript and the links there were broken - so i dropped it.. But now after you send it, I've digged in more, and found the user in github, so he developed esri-loder.. I checked his code and found out that when we write `window.require` it really uses `dojo require`.. so the solution is simple.. I will write a solution now (Thanks for the push @barbsan)

Comment: I've found also something on SO - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805234/import-existing-amd-module-into-es6-module). But this solution makes use of gulp.

Comment: I've seen all of those links before I've posted.. but i thought there is must be simple solution.. And I found it.. magical `window.`. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for using `dojo`'s `require` we need simply to write `window.require` and it will work.

without writing `window.` it is failing in the build process `Can't resolve 'esri/Map'`

For esri users who wants to use some nice loader - check out this [one](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader)

code example:

```
export default class myMap {
     constructor(div) {
        window.require(['esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView'], (esriMap, esriMapView) => {
            const map = new esriMap({
                basemap: "streets"
            });

            const view = new esriMapView({
                container: div,
                map: map,
                zoom: 4,
                center: [15, 65]
            });
        });
    }
}
```