# How to import downloadjs into react js file?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to use downloadjs - https://github.com/rndme/download - and have installed it via npm, I have then checked and it is in my node modules and in my package.json as a dependency.

I have then included the following in the .js doc I want to add download functionality to:

```
import downloadjs from 'downloadjs';
```

And then further down I try to use it, using function download(), but I am still getting the error "'download' is not defined"

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `downloadjs` a locally made module or your module available in `npm` ?

Answer (score 1):

the library you are using is not maintained for 3 years by now & it's using the old commonjs syntax to import & use the library. you might be able to use it this way:

```js
import downloadjs from "downloadjs";
```

but as far as it's an AMD module, if you get errors, then the following thread may help you:
[Import existing AMD module into ES6 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805234/import-existing-amd-module-into-es6-module)

Answer (score 1):

Seems maybe the documentation was out of date as once I used function `downloadjs(param, param)` instead of `download(param, param)` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

-Try again:

*npm install downloadjs*

-And then:

*import download from 'downloadjs';*

-And you may be using it the wrong way? Here is an example:

```
  const res=await axios.get(`http://something/something/download/${id}`,{
  responseType: 'blob' })
  download(res.data);
```

}